# How to use a login screen in Grails to redirect different user to different information?

Tags: grails

I am trying to develop a Groovy/Grails app that needs to redirect different users on login to different information. In particular: I have a database of restaurants and items that belong to each restaurant. Each restaurant needs to be redirected to a list view of its own particular items and not be able to view other restaurant's items. That needs to be decided on login based on the login credentials. There is a big database table with all items of all restaurants, and having separate tables for each restaurant is not an option.

What should I be looking first? tutorials, reference docs? Links I find very helpful.

I downloaded this: http://www.strattonenglish.co.uk/login_tutorial.pdf , but it deosnt really address my situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the [grails spring security core plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) (or at least one way to do this would be to use the plugin, but you are free to choose otherwise)

If you chose the plugin, then I suggest starting with the plugin's user guide. And for more advanced things, you can always fallback to the spring security (which the plugin is built on top) docs.

As an extra, the same question was sort of asked on the [mailing list here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Spring-Security-Filters-Chain-td3300646.html) (if you want some more relevant info)

Comment: what about the multi-tenant-single db plugin?

Comment: tbh, I have not used that plugin, but if it covers your needs then it could be an option.

Comment: honestly, i would rather go with the official spring security plugin, since it has waaaay more documentation, but some people on the official grails forum claim that the only thing that really achieves what i need are those multi tenant plugins!   Is there a simple example on how to use the security-core plugin to restrict different tenants from viewing each other's data in the same db?

Comment: Please take a look at this if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060768/error-executing-script-createauthdomains-null-scripts-init-groovy-the-system-c