# Error executing script CreateAuthDomains: null\scripts\Init.groovy (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am trying to build an app that makes use of the acegi and multitenant-plugin in grails. I am following the instructions from this tutorial:

http://ridingthetiger.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_a_Secure,_Multi-Tenant_Web_App_with_Grails

however when I get to this instruction:

```
grails create-auth-domains org.racetrack.User org.racetrack.Role Requestmap
```

I get this error:

```
Running script C:\Users\roise\.grails\1.3.7\projects\racetrack\plugins\acegi-0.5.2\scripts\CreateAuthDomains.groovy
Error executing script CreateAuthDomains: null\scripts\Init.groovy (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: null\scripts\Init.groovy (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at gant.Gant$_closure1.doCall(Gant.groovy:128)
    at gant.Gant$_closure1.call(Gant.groovy)
    at _SecurityTargets_groovy.run(_SecurityTargets_groovy:25)
    at _SecurityTargets_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at CreateAuthDomains.run(CreateAuthDomains:23)
    at CreateAuthDomains$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:606)
Error executing script CreateAuthDomains: null\scripts\Init.groovy (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I have tried to follow the tutorial to the last comma. The only thing that is different is that i am developing in STS and I cannot run the create-app command from the command line, I actually have to create a new app from the New menu. The other three commands I have got up to so far - I have entered and executed exactly as shown.

Comment: Since I don't have an answer, I can just point out that the article mentions Grails 1.2.2 while I can see you are using 1.3.7

Comment: I tried that too. It's didnt work. :(   P.S. What is the difference between "acegi" and the "spring security core" plugin ?

Comment: If my memory serves correctly acegi became spring security around the time version 2 of s2 was out.

Comment: ?!. so why is "acegi" still around. shouldn't people work with spring security only?

Comment: Yes, you should be using Spring Security now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that "GRAILS_HOME" environment variable is not set.

From the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#downloadingAndInstalling):

On Windows this is typically a matter of setting an environment variable under My Computer/Advanced/Environment Variables

Answer (score 0):

I believe that @arcdegree is right that the problem is because a script cannot figure out what GRAILS_HOME is but in my case that environment variable was set correctly and I was still experiencing the problem.

What I found to fix my problem and I believe will fix your problem is that the command you are trying to run (create-auth-domains ) is accessing a script (CreateAuthDomains.groovy) within the acegi plugin that needs updating. Now, this question is quite old with no accepted answers so I'm not sure if you are still experiencing this problem but I do think this answer will help anyone else looking into a similar problem. Mine stems from trying to use an old plugin for jsecurity that has been replaced with a newer plugin but I was intent on using the same thing a document I was referring to had used.

Your script in this case, CreateAuthDomains, probably uses an old reference to grailsHome and includeTargets that should be replaced with a single line that calls grailsScript("Init") instead. So, comment out these lines:

- `grailsHome = Ant.project.properties."environment.GRAILS_HOME"`
- `includeTargets << new File ("${grailsHome}/scripts/Init.groovy")`

then add this one line

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("Init")
```

Save the file and try your command again.